# Why are decimal values getting stored incorrectly in MySql table from my asp.net core web app

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net-core, decimal

I'm developing a web app using asp.net core and MySql as database, the purpose of the app is to act like a digital storage. The app is able to add, delete, update products. The issues I'm having is when I add products to my database table through the web app. For example I want to add a product with the weight of 4,21 and when is store it in the database it shows 421,00 instead. The Weight column in the database is set to Decimal(18,2). I'm using cPanel to host my web app.

I fixed the issue locally with this code:

```
 public async Task<bool> AddProduct(string articleNumber, decimal purchasePrice, decimal sellingPrice, decimal weight, decimal dimension, string material, int quantity)
    {
        try
        {
            var exist = await ArticleNumberExists(articleNumber);
            if (exist)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("article number already exists");
                return false;
            }
            var formattedPurchasePrice = purchasePrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var formattedSellingPrice = sellingPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var formattedWeight = weight.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var formattedDimension = dimension.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            var product = new Product()
            {
                ArticleNumber = articleNumber,
                PurchasePrice = purchasePrice,
                SellingPrice = sellingPrice,
                Weight = weight,
                Dimension = dimension,
                PurchasePrice = decimal.Parse(formattedPurchasePrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                SellingPrice = decimal.Parse(formattedSellingPrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Weight = decimal.Parse(formattedWeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Dimension = decimal.Parse(formattedDimension, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Material = material,
                Quantity = quantity
            };
            await _context.Products.AddAsync(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _logger.LogError("failed to add product");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This stores the values correctly in the database, value 4,21 stored as 4,21 in database but only when running this locally.

When deploying the web app this does not seem to work anymore, I cannot figure out why.

Edit: Inlcuding my view and javascript

```html
@model ProductVM
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Produkter";
}

<section class="vh-100 gradient-custom">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">

            <div id="centerText" style="text-align: center;"></div>


            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                <div class="card bg-dark text-white" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
                    <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">

                        <div class="mb-md-5 mt-md-4 pb-5">

                            <h2 class="fw-bold mb-2 text-uppercase">Lägg till produkter</h2>
                            <p class="text-white-50 mb-5">Skriv in produkt information</p>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input type="button" id="typeGenerateArticleNumberX" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="Generera Artikel nummer" onclick="generateUniqueArticleNumber()" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="ArticleNumber" type="text" id="typeArticleNumberX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Artikel nummer" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ArticleNumber"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="PurchasePrice" type="text" id="typePurchasePriceX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Inköpspris" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="PurchasePrice"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="SellingPrice" type="text" id="typeSellingPriceX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Pris" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="SellingPrice"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="Weight" type="text" id="typeWeightX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Vikt" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Weight"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input type="text" id="typeDimensionX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Mått" /> @* Behöver inte ha asp-for för mått eftersom kunde inte alltid kommer att sätta den. *@
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="Material" type="text" id="typeMaterialX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Material" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Material"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
                                <input asp-for="Quantity" type="text" id="typeQuantityX" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Antal" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="button" id="formSubmitButton">Lägg till</button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="button" id="printButton">Skriv ut etikett</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script>

    // Attach the printLabel function to the "Skriv ut etikett" button click event


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#printButton').click(function () {
            printLabel();
        });

        $('#formSubmitButton').click(function () {
            addProduct();
        });
    });

    function clearFields() {
        $('#typeArticleNumberX').val('');
        $('#typePurchasePriceX').val('');
        $('#typeSellingPriceX').val('');
        $('#typeWeightX').val('');
        $('#typeDimensionX').val('');
        $('#typeMaterialX').val('');
        $('#typeQuantityX').val('');
    }

    function generateUniqueArticleNumber() {
        var articleNumberField = document.getElementById("typeArticleNumberX");

        // Generate a random 6-digit numeric article number
        var articleNumber = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);

        var url = 'CheckArticleNumberAsync?articleNumber=' + articleNumber;
        console.log(url);
        // Check if the generated article number already exists in the database
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (exists) {
                console.log('Article Number Exists:', exists);

                if (exists) {
                    // If the article number exists, generate a new one recursively
                    console.log('Article Number exists. Generating a new one...');
                    generateUniqueArticleNumber();
                } else {
                    // Set the generated unique article number to the input field
                    articleNumberField.value = articleNumber;
                    console.log('Unique Article Number set:', articleNumber);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                // Handle error if the check fails
                console.error('AJAX, Failed to check article number existence.');
            }
        });
    }

    function addProduct() {
        var articleNumber = $('#typeArticleNumberX').val();
        var purchasePrice = $('#typePurchasePriceX').val();
        var sellingPrice = $('#typeSellingPriceX').val();
        var weight = $('#typeWeightX').val();
        var dimension = $('#typeDimensionX').val();
        var material = $('#typeMaterialX').val();
        var quantity = $('#typeQuantityX').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/Product',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                articleNumber: articleNumber,
                purchasePrice: purchasePrice,
                sellingPrice: sellingPrice,
                weight: weight,
                dimension: dimension,
                material: material,
                quantity: quantity
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    clearFields();
                    $('#centerText').text('Product added successfully');
                    $('#centerText').css('color', 'green');
                } else {
                    console.error(response.error);
                    $('#centerText').text(response.error);
                    $('#centerText').css('color', 'red');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Failed to add product:', error);
                console.log('Server response:', xhr.responseText);
                $('#centerText').text('Failed to add product. Please try again.');
                $('#centerText').css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    }





    function printLabel() {
        // Gather input values
        var articleNumber = $('#typeArticleNumberX').val();
        var purchasePrice = $('#typePurchasePriceX').val();
        var sellingPrice = $('#typeSellingPriceX').val();
        var weight = $('#typeWeightX').val();
        var dimension = $('#typeDimensionX').val();
        var material = $('#typeMaterialX').val();
        var quantity = $('#typeQuantityX').val();

        // Create form data
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('ArticleNumber', articleNumber);
        formData.append('PurchasePrice', purchasePrice);
        formData.append('SellingPrice', sellingPrice);
        formData.append('Weight', weight);
        formData.append('Dimension', dimension);
        formData.append('Material', material);
        formData.append('Quantity', quantity);

        // Send AJAX request to print label
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/PrintLabel', // Replace with the actual controller and action name
            method: 'POST',
            processData: false,  // Prevent jQuery from processing the data
            contentType: false,  // Prevent jQuery from setting the content type
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle success (if needed)
                console.log('Label printed successfully:', response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // Handle error (if needed)
                console.error('AJAX, Failed to print label:', error);
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: perhaps you are viewing it differently? it may be displaying it as a percentage if using myphpadmin or something like that.

Comment: Also, using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` it going to use `.` as the decimal separator. Perhaps locally you are defaulting to your local culture, which uses `,` as a decimal point, but then it gets parsed on the servers culture and the comma gets ignored

Comment: Could language (culture) settings be different? In English speaking world comma is used as thousand separator, not as a decimal separator. Period is used as decimal separator there. This difference could lead to different parsing of data containing comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely has nothing to do with the database and everything to do with the default Culture asp.net is running with on your web host.

Locally, you appear to be running a non-English culture which uses `,` as decimal separator.

On the live server, it won't understand that and likely treats. `,` as a thousands separator (so, basically gets ignored).

Submitting `"4,21"` as a string, it is going to get converted to a Decimal by the default culture, and so the `weight` is coming in as `421`.  Convert that to a string and back to a decimal makes no difference.

One solution: Change the parameters to Strings and do the parsing yourself in whatever culture you want. You can also change the default culture:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: I tried to change the default culture as you suggested but now when I try to store the decimal value 22,54 I can see that it gets stored as 2,254.

Comment: can you add the javascript code you use to submit values? `2,254` is `2254` in english culture, so I'm not sure if it was really divided by 10 (makes no sense) or if it is still doing the same thing. You have to set default culture early on (during app initialization)

Comment: `Startup.Configure` is a valid place to add it. Your app won't be very useful outside your country that way, though. Probably better to format the string on the client to look like the InvariantCulture version:  `22.54`

Comment: or just parse the string on client and submit as a number

Comment: Ahhh my bad, your suggestion worked! I had a method that divided the decimals as a workaround and forgot to remove it and thats why the decimal 22,54 got stored as 2,254 instead. I removed the method and viola, It worked smoothly! I implemented the default culture in my program.cs class and used the swedish CultureInfo("sv-SE").